# go-ethereum sign provides different signature than nodejs ethers

Tags: node.js, cryptography, go-ethereum

I need signatures made in golang verifiable in nodejs and conversely (with ethereum wallets/private keys).
But the two libraries that I use provide different results for the signing of a message. I don't know if it is because I make a mistake somewhere or the signing algorithms are differents. I tried other options, but could not find something that gives the same results in both sides.

Golang code with "go-ethereum":

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {

    hexPrivateKey := "0xae78c8b502571dba876742437f8bc78b689cf8518356c0921393d89caaf284ce"
    dataToSign := "bou"

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(hexPrivateKey[2:])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // keccak256 hash of the data
    dataBytes := []byte(dataToSign)
    hashData := crypto.Keccak256Hash(dataBytes)

    signatureBytes, err := crypto.Sign(hashData.Bytes(), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    signature = hexutil.Encode(signatureBytes)

    fmt.Println(signature) // 0xc83d417a3b99535e784a72af0d9772c019c776aa0dfe4313c001a5548f6cf254477f5334c30da59531bb521278edc98f1959009253dda4ee9f63fe5562ead5aa00
}
```

nodejs code with "ethers":

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

let hexPrivateKey = "0xae78c8b502571dba876742437f8bc78b689cf8518356c0921393d89caaf284ce";
let dataToSign := "bou"

let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(hexPrivateKey);

// keccak256 hash of the data
let hashData = ethers.utils.id(dataToSign);

let signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(hashData));

console.log(signature); // 0x80512c504128c66590fc359fd1e663ec51144086beef775e4e3be14e949fdead5839d90f4789e80bb264dc90474148143b09c286d3d75ba33e20e4117bf5c2881c
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but hopefully I can still help some people out as I've also been at this point before.

You'd have the replace the recovery ID to match the signature from ethers. I've created a simple reposity which fixes this: https://github.com/etaaa/Golang-Ethereum-Personal-Sign

Hope that fixes your problem!

Answer (score 1):

The guys at ethers.js found my issue. As they explain there: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/823#issuecomment-625953096, the `signMessage` function of ethers.js uses EIP-191 with the personal_sign format, so it prefixes the message with `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"`.

To get the same result in ethers.js as in golang, we must use a raw SigningKey, not the Wallet wrapper:

```
const hexPrivateKey = "0xae78c8b502571dba876742437f8bc78b689cf8518356c0921393d89caaf284ce";
const signingKey = new ethers.utils.SigningKey(hexPrivateKey);

const signature = signingKey.signDigest(ethers.utils.id("bou"));
//{ r: '0xc83d417a3b99535e784a72af0d9772c019c776aa0dfe4313c001a5548f6cf254',
//  s: '0x477f5334c30da59531bb521278edc98f1959009253dda4ee9f63fe5562ead5aa',
//  _vs: '0x477f5334c30da59531bb521278edc98f1959009253dda4ee9f63fe5562ead5aa',
//  recoveryParam: 0,
//  v: 27 }

ethers.utils.joinSignature(signature);
// "0xc83d417a3b99535e784a72af0d9772c019c776aa0dfe4313c001a5548f6cf254477f5334c30da59531bb521278edc98f1959009253dda4ee9f63fe5562ead5aa1b"
```

The only additional thing to consider is that the last 2 digits of this signature in ethers.js will not be the same as the golang ones, as the ethers.js joinSignature function uses the v at the end, but the golang one showed above uses the recovery parameter at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a library https://github.com/storyicon/sigverify that encapsulates the function of verifying Ethereum signatures in golang, including EIP712 and ERC1271.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.