# Implementing Ethereum personal_sign (EIP-191) from go-ethereum gives different signature from ethers.js

Tags: go, cryptography, ethereum, signature, ethers.js

I am attempting to generate a `personal_sign` in Golang like its implemented in ethers.js. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682191/go-ethereum-sign-provides-different-signature-than-nodejs-ethers) but that ended up using the regular `sign` over the personal `sign_implementation`.

Ethers

```js
// keccak256 hash of the data
let dataHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(
  ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(JSON.stringify(dataToSign))
);

//0x8d218fc37d2fd952b2d115046b786b787e44d105cccf156882a2e74ad993ee13

let signature = await wallet.signMessage(dataHash); // 0x469b07327fc41a2d85b7e69bcf4a9184098835c47cc7575375e3a306c3718ae35702af84f3a62aafeb8aab6a455d761274263d79e7fc99fbedfeaf759d8dc9361c
```

Golang:

```golang
func signHash(data []byte) common.Hash {
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n%d%s", len(data), data)

    return crypto.Keccak256Hash([]byte(msg))
}

privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(hexPrivateKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

dataHash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(dataToSign) //0x8d218fc37d2fd952b2d115046b786b787e44d105cccf156882a2e74ad993ee13

signHash := signHash(dataHash.Bytes())

signatureBytes, err := crypto.Sign(signHash.Bytes(), privateKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}


// signatureBytes 0xec56178d3dca77c3cee7aed83cdca2ffa2bec8ef1685ce5103cfa72c27beb61313d91b9ad9b9a644b0edf6352cb69f2f8acd25297e3c64cd060646242e0455ea00
```

As you can see the hash is the same, but the signature is different:

`0x469b07327fc41a2d85b7e69bcf4a9184098835c47cc7575375e3a306c3718ae35702af84f3a62aafeb8aab6a455d761274263d79e7fc99fbedfeaf759d8dc9361c` Ethers

`0xec56178d3dca77c3cee7aed83cdca2ffa2bec8ef1685ce5103cfa72c27beb61313d91b9ad9b9a644b0edf6352cb69f2f8acd25297e3c64cd060646242e0455ea00` Golang

Looking at the source code of Ethers.js I can't find anything different aside how the padding is managed.

**Edit**
Check the approved answer

```
signHash(data []byte) common.Hash {
    hexData := hexutil.Encode(data)
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n%d%s", len(hexData), hexData)

    return crypto.Keccak256Hash([]byte(msg))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug in the JavaScript code.

From the documentation of [`signer.signMessage()`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signMessage) (see the *Note* section), it appears that a string is UTF8 encoded and binary data must be passed as `TypedArray` or `Array`.
The Keccak hash is returned hex encoded, i.e. as string, and is therefore UTF8 encoded, which is incorrect. Instead, it must be converted to a `TypedArray`. For this purpose the library provides the function `ethers.utils.arrayify()`.

The following JavaScript is based on the posted code, but performs the required hex decoding:

```js
(async () => {
    let privateKey = "0x8da4ef21b864d2cc526dbdb2a120bd2874c36c9d0a1fb7f8c63d7f7a8b41de8f";
    let dataToSign = {"data1":"value1","data2":"value2"};

    let dataHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(
      ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(JSON.stringify(dataToSign))
    );
    dataHashBin = ethers.utils.arrayify(dataHash)
    
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
    let signature = await wallet.signMessage(dataHashBin); 
    
    document.getElementById("signature").innerHTML = signature; // 0xfcc3e9431c139b5f943591af78c280b939595ce9df66210b7b8bb69565bdd2af7081a8acc0cbb5ea55bd0d673b176797966a5180c11ac297b7e6344c5822e66d1c
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.0.umd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="signature"></p>
```

which produces the following signature:

```
0xfcc3e9431c139b5f943591af78c280b939595ce9df66210b7b8bb69565bdd2af7081a8acc0cbb5ea55bd0d673b176797966a5180c11ac297b7e6344c5822e66d1c
```

---

The Go code below is based on the unmodified posted Go code, but using key and data from the JavaScript code for a comparison:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

func signHash(data []byte) common.Hash {
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n%d%s", len(data), data)
    return crypto.Keccak256Hash([]byte(msg))
}

func main() {

    hexPrivateKey := "8da4ef21b864d2cc526dbdb2a120bd2874c36c9d0a1fb7f8c63d7f7a8b41de8f"
    dataMap := map[string]string{"data1":"value1","data2":"value2"}
    dataToSign, _ := json.Marshal(dataMap)

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(hexPrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }

    dataHash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(dataToSign) //0x8d218fc37d2fd952b2d115046b786b787e44d105cccf156882a2e74ad993ee13

    signHash := signHash(dataHash.Bytes())

    signatureBytes, err := crypto.Sign(signHash.Bytes(), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println("0x" + hex.EncodeToString(signatureBytes))
}
```

The Go Code gives the following signature:

```
0xfcc3e9431c139b5f943591af78c280b939595ce9df66210b7b8bb69565bdd2af7081a8acc0cbb5ea55bd0d673b176797966a5180c11ac297b7e6344c5822e66d01
```

---

Both signatures match *except* for the last byte.

The JavaScript code returns the signature in the format `r|s|v` (see [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bytes/#signature-raw)). `v` is one byte in size and is just the value in which both signatures differ.

It is `v = 27 + rid` where `rid` is the recovery ID. The recovery ID has values between 0 and 3, so `v` has values between 27 and 30 or 0x1b and 0x1e (see [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38909)).

The Go code, on the other hand, returns the recovery ID in the last byte instead of `v`. So that the signature of the Go code matches that of the JavaScript code in the last byte as well, the recovery ID must be replaced by `v`:

```golang
signatureBytes[64] += 27
fmt.Println("0x" + hex.EncodeToString(signatureBytes))
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the correct answer. Because I have to match the JS implementation, I modified the go signHash function to encode the Byte Array into a Hex, after fixing the last byte it returns the same signature. Will post the code on my original answer as an update for future reference.